# Как добавить meta_data при помощи REST api woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rest

Сделал api для передачи данных между 1С и WooCommerce.После выборки из базы формирую запрос но мета данные в базе и созданных товаров не добавляются (товары создаются ).

```
 require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require 'app/bootstrap.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$config = new Config_class();

$result = $config->connect_to_db();

$woocommerce = new Client(
    'url',
    'ck_',
    'cs_',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v1',
    ]
);

if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data = [
      'name' => $row['search_text'],
      'type' => 'simple',
      'regular_price' => $row['price'],
      'description' => $row['product_content'],
      'short_description' => $row['pro_title'],
      'sku' => $row['barcode'],
      'images' => [
          [
              'src' => 'url' .$row['photo_id']. '/1_1.jpg',
              'position' => 0,
              'alt' => $row['pro_title'],
          ],
          [
              'src' => 'url' .$row['photo_id']. '/1_2.jpg',
              'position' => 1,
              'alt' => $row['pro_title'],
          ]
      ],
      'meta_data' => [
        [
          'key' => '_product_id_1c',
          'value' => $row['id_1c']
        ],

      ]
    ];

   $post_data = $woocommerce->post('products' , $data);
  }

}
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так?

Comment: Да все не так. Вы где такой код взяли? Класс WooCommerce (на экземпляр которого ссылается глобальная переменная $woocommerce) не содержит метода post. Ваш код должен падать с ошибкой 500.

Comment: И то, что вы используете прямой доступ к базе ( fetch_assoc()) ) - очень плохая практика.

Comment: это кусок кода... с 500 он не падает.... добавил в вопрос весь код.

Comment: А откуда вообще все эти классы? Например, Client. В WordPress и WooCommerce из нет.

Comment: @KAGGDesign https://github.com/nikita6631/wc-api-php , $config мой класс.

Comment: Ну а почему вы в вопросе сразу этого не пишете? Как угадать, что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @KAGGDesign ну... буду знать на будущее. Прошу понять и простить )))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73137/discussion-between-kagg-design-and--).