# Как правильно зарегистрировать custom_meta_field для rest api woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Написал плагин и API для передачи данных между 1С и WordPpress , у меня есть кастомные поля которые хочу заполнять при помощи API. При запросе товары создаются, но мета поля нет. Думаю нужно зарегистрировать их во время установки плагина. Пробую так , но безуспешно:

```
function install_plugin() {

  register_meta( 'post', '_product_id_1c', array(
    'type'              => 'string',
    'description'       => 'id from 1c',
    'single'            => false,
    'show_in_rest'      => true,
  ) );

  register_rest_field('product' , '_product_id_1c' , null);

  flush_rewrite_rules();
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__ , 'install_plugin');
```

[Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785067/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-meta-data-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-rest-api-woocommerce) на предыдущий вопрос по теме

Comment: Вы регистрируте мета к посту, а надо к продукту. `register_meta( 'product' ... `

Comment: @KAGGDesign По моему это вполне тянет на ответ

Comment: @KAGGDesign та я уже и посту и продукту делал... все равно не записывает туда...